# Anyway to display Visualforce pages,triggers in dependencies of apex class

Tags: apex

Today, i have deleted an apex class without any issues. But, later i configured that the deleted class is used in Visualforce pages and Triggers..That was a disaster for me. Before deleting i have checked 'Show Depencies' in apex class and didn't find anything there.

Is there anyway to know the usage of the class in either visualforce or triggers or in other apex class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, these is no native SFDC feature which helps you in this. There is also an idea open for this.

> https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000i3yRAAQ